# Drupal Install resulting in white pages

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I am installing Drupal 7.33 on the latest version of Linux Mint. I've installed MySQL via the software repos...same with Apache, PHP, MySQL Workbench, and so on. Drupal itself I am following the instructions from the website (downloading .tar.gz to /var/www/html, extracting it, setting permissions, etc.).

Now I have run into an apparently common, but curious problem. After completing my work, I browsed to localhost/install.php; everything appeared to be proceeding smoothly until I hit the 'Setup Database Page'; instead of moving onto the next page after I clicked the button at the bottom, it appeared to reload the current page; a quick check of the database shows many tables having been created, so it appears to have access. Navigation back to the page has me run through the first few steps, followed by skipping the next few, and landing on the 'Configure Site' page which, when filled out and the button pressed, leads me to another white page.

Somehow I feel this is a permission's problem, yet I am fairly certain I followed the instructions to the letter. Does anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you give write permissions to sites/default/?

Comment: Yeah, no dice. I'm thinking of making a screen video.

Comment: What does the error log say?

Comment: I give you...video of the install process: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s8XJKfbjp3Y&feature=youtu.be

Comment: I'm not going to watch a 12 minutes video to analyze every step. Telling about the php error log would be much more effective.

Comment: Will do. I'm out with the flu at the moment, be back as soon as possible.

Comment: Here we go...from the Apache log: [Mon Nov 17 08:04:34.032786 2014] [:error] [pid 11874] [client 127.0.0.1:46702] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function field_attach_load() in /var/www/html/includes/entity.inc on line 316, referer: http://localhost/install.php?profile=standard&locale=en

Comment: The function field_attach_load() is defined in the file drupal/modules/field/field.attach.inc . The file may not exist or the reading permissions of the file are not set properly.

Comment: Right, let me try it this way. When installing Drupal, should I use su or sudo?

Comment: Check permissions with `ls -l` and change permissions with `chmod` or `chown`. See manpages how to use the commands. Example `man chmod`.